# Why this PDE causes internal 1/0 division?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, bugs, symbolic

**Bug introduced in 11.3 and persisting through 12.0.0**

In 11.2 `DSolve` return unevaluated.

Assigned WRI case number **4210941**

---

Using 11.3 on Windows 10, this input

```
ClearAll[w, x, y, a, b, lambda, mu];

pde = D[w[x, y], x] + (a*Exp[lambda*x]*y^2 + mu*y - 
        a*b^2*Exp[(lambda + 2 mu)*x])*D[w[x, y], y] == 0;

sol = DSolve[pde, w[x, y], {x, y}]
```

gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When changing `2 mu` to just `mu` the kernel error goes away

```
ClearAll[w, x, y, a, b, lambda, mu];
pde = D[w[x, y], x] + (a*Exp[lambda*x]*y^2 + mu*y - 
       a*b^2*Exp[(lambda + mu)*x])*D[w[x, y], y] == 0;

sol = DSolve[pde, w[x, y], {x, y}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

why does `DSolve` generate this kernel error on first input above but not the second? Is this a bug?

Comment: I don't see how you can declare it a bug when you are working a different equation.  If you also divide both  mu's in your equation by 2, you get the same error.

Comment: Fixed with same solution (13.2.0).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`DSolve` undoubtedly is attempting to use the usual Method of Characteristics to solve `pde`.  This would begin as follows:

```
y'[x] == (Coefficient[pde // First, D[w[x, y], y]] /. y -> y[x])
(* y'[x] == -a b^2 E^((lambda + 2 mu) x) + mu y[x] + a E^(lambda x) y[x]^2 *)
DSolve[%, y[x], x]
```

Unfortunately, `DSolve` again fails with many of the same error messages as for the PDE, returning

```
(* {{y[x] -> Indeterminate}} *)
```

Certainly, the inability of `DSolve` to produce a solution for any particular differential equation should not be considered a bug.  However, `DSolve` should be trapping internal errors and should return unevaluated instead of returning `y[x] -> Indeterminate`.  I would agree with [Nasser](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/70/nasser) that this is a bug, although a minor one.

Incidentally, `DSolve` can obtain a solution for

```
sol = DSolve[pde /. {mu -> 1, lambda -> 1}, w[x, y], {x, y}] // Flatten
(* {w[x, y] -> C[1][-(1/2) I (a b E^(2 x) + 2 ArcTanh[(E^-x y)/b])]} *)
```

and perhaps for other particular values of `mu` and `lambda`.

**Addendum: General Solution Obtained Empirically**

In fact, `DSolve` solves `pde` for all rational values I have tried for `mu` and `lambda`.  From comparing a few such solutions, a general solution can be guessed.

```
(* {w[x, y] -> C[1][-I*(a*b*E^((mu + lambda) x)/(mu + lambda) + 
    ArcTanh[y E^(-mu x)/b])]]} *)
```

which can be verified by substituting this solution into `pde`.  Irrational numbers seem to work too, provided that they do not have too many digits after the decimal point.

**Addendum: General Solution Derived by Method of Characteristics**

As shown in the fist code block of this answer, `DSolve` fails to solve the ODE for characteristics of `pde`.  However, with the transformation `y -> Sqrt[-b^2]*E^(mu x)*z[x]`, progress can be made.

```
ode = y'[x] == -a b^2 E^((lambda + 2 mu) x) + mu y[x] + a E^(lambda x) y[x]^2
Simplify[% /. y -> Function[{x}, Sqrt[-b^2]*E^(mu x)*z[x]], b > 0]
(* a b E^((lambda + 2 mu) x) + a b E^((lambda + 2 mu) x) z[x]^2 + 
   I E^(mu x) z'[x] == 0 *)
```

(Because `b` enters the equation only quadratically, it can be assumed positive without loss of generality.  Next, apply `DSolve` and transform from `z` back to `y`.

```
Flatten@DSolve[%, z[x], x] /. Rule -> Equal /. z[x] -> y[x]/(I b*E^(mu x))
(* {-((I E^(-mu x) y[x])/b) == I Tanh[(a b E^((lambda + mu) x))/(lambda + mu)
    - I C[1]]} *)
```

The Method of Characteristics requires `C[1]` in  terms of the variables.

```
Simplify[Solve[%, C[1]], C[2] \[Element] Integers] // Flatten
(* {C[1] -> -((I a b E^((lambda + mu) x))/(lambda + mu)) - 
    I ArcTanh[(E^(-mu x) y[x])/b] - Pi C[2]} *)
```

Because `C[1]` is an arbitrary constant, `Pi C[2]` can be absorbed into it (or, equivalently set to zero).

```
{C[1] -> -I ((a b E^((lambda + mu) x))/(lambda + mu) + ArcTanh[(E^(-mu x) y[x])/b])}
```

According to the Method of Characteristics, `w` is an arbitrary function of the right side of the expression immediately above, which is equivalent to the expression given in the first addendum.  (Note that `C[1]` has different meanings in the two addenda, because different equations are being solved - `pde` and the corresponding `ode`.)